# Как в Python получить слово по позиции символа

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Есть некая строка и номер символа в этой строке:

```
some = "какой-то текст в качестве примера"
symbol = 18
```

Как можно получить слово (в данном примере `качестве`) при таких условиях?

UPD1:
Как временное решение сделал что-то такое:

```
def finder(text, pos):
    posS = 0
    posE = len(text)

    _posS = pos
    while _posS>posS:
        if text[_posS] in (" ", "\n"): posS = _posS+1
        else: _posS -= 1

    _posE = pos
    while _posE<posE:
        if text[_posE] in (" ", "\n"): posE = _posE
        else: _posE += 1

    return (posS, posE)
```

Однако как по мне этот вариант слишком долгий в дальнейшей перспективе да и в целом уверен есть что-то понятнее и лучше.

Comment: `print(some[symbol-1:symbol-1+some[symbol-1:].find(' ')])`

Comment: Данный вариант не работает назад, увы(

Comment: @Firec, надо чтобы и слева брало полностью слово, даже если symbol немного дальше?

Comment: @entithat, да. Полностью всё слово, в рамках которого находится символ.

Comment: Как же жаль, что нельзя отмечать два ответа как верные. И entithat, и Zhihar помогли. Спасибо им!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаем так:

- Из строки взяли все слова в список
- Прошлись с помощью `map` - нашли начальные индексы слов
- Прошлись с помощью `filter` - нашли индексы, которые меньше, чем `pos`
- Взяли слово от самого большого индекса, который остался (это начало нашего слова) до первого пробела начиная от этого слова.

```
def findWord(s, pos):
    if s.count(' ') < 1: return s # Если в строке нет пробелов
    idx = list(filter(lambda x: x < pos, map(
        lambda x: s.index(x), s.split(' '))))[-1]
    return s[idx: idx + s[idx:].index(' ') + 1]
    
    
print(findWord("какой-то текст в качестве примера", 18)) # качестве
print(findWord("какой-то текст в качестве примера", 10)) # текст
print(findWord("какой-то текст в качестве примера", 8))  # какой-то
```

Либо:

- Ищем индекс пробела слева
- Ищем индекс пробела справа
- Вырезаем слово по этим границам

```
def findWord(s, pos):
    if pos > len(s):
        raise Exception('Position is greater than length of the word')

    lsi = -1 if s[:pos].count(' ') == 0 else s[:pos].rindex(' ')
    psi = len(s) if s[pos:].count(' ') == 0 else pos + s[pos:].index(' ')

    return s[lsi + 1:psi]


print(findWord("There are more twins now than ever before.", 19)) # twins
```

P.S. Если надо решение в одну строку:

```
s = "There are more twins now than ever before."
pos = 14

print(s[-1 if s[:pos].count(' ') == 0 else s[:pos].rindex(' ') + 1:len(s) if s[pos:].count(' ') == 0 else pos + s[pos:].index(' ')])  # more
```

Answer (score 2):

например так:

основная суть -

1. взять последнее слово до искомой позиции (учесть нулевую позицию)
2. взять первое слово после искомой позиции
3. соединить
4. учесть ситуацию, когда позиция находится вне строки или на разделителе

код:

```
some = "какой-то текст в качестве примера"
symbol = 18

if -1 < symbol < len(some) and some[symbol] != ' ':
    block_s = '' if symbol == 0 else some[:symbol].split()[-1]
    block_e = some[symbol:].split()[0]
    
    res = block_s + block_e
else:
    res = 'вне слова'

print(res)
```

дешево и сердито

первый блок можно получить чуть более хитро, но и более коротко:

```
block_s = ([''] + some[:symbol].split())[-1]
```

т.е. избежать списка нулевой длины дополнив список вначале пустой строкой

Ну и для любителей однострочных решений:

```
res = ([''] + some[:symbol].split())[-1] + some[symbol:].split()[0] if -1 < symbol < len(some) and some[symbol] != ' ' else '***вне слова***'
```